# LSTM - time series predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am following this tutorial [LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) and I wonder how to map this to a multi-time series input. I have a dataset of several time-series and I want to predict for each time series the future. I don't know how to scale LSTM to several time-series.

The aim is to avoid to make a model for each time series as I have 40k of time series.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Process one by one**

Just do exactly the same in a loop like this:

```
for epoch in range(numberOfEpochs):
    for sequence in yourSequences:
        model.reset_states()

        #1 - do the entire training for this sequence (1 epoch only)    
        #you may use "model.train_on_batch" to avoid some overhead in "fit"

        #or 2 - do the entire predictoins for this sequence
```

**Process all together**

Just pack the series in the first dimension of the input. No change is necessary in the model

When defining the input shape, use `batch_input=(number_of_time_series,length,features)` or `batch_input_shape=(number_of_time_series,length,features)`. (You may need a smaller batch size, because 40K is too much)

- Make sure to use `shuffle=False` in every training command.
- If your batch is not 40k, make sure to process the entire length (the entire training or prediction) of each batch, then you use `model.reset_states()` and start a new group of sequences.

.

```
batch_size = ....
for epoch in range(numberOfEpochs):
    firstSeq = 0
    lastSeq = firstSeq + batch_size

    while lastSeq <= len(sequences):

        model.reset_states()
        batch = sequences[firstSeq:lastSeq]

        #train the entire batch (one epoch only)
        #or predict for the entire batch

        firstSeq += batch_size
        lastSeq += batch_size
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using separate Time series, I don't think keeping stateful = True is a good Idea.

Actually, your problem is closer to the 'generic' use of LSTMs.

Try to concatenate your series in a 2d array where each line is corresponding to a serie. Then reshape your data like that : (number_of_series , timesteps (length of a single serie) , 1), then feed it to your network.

Depending of the length of your series, you may need to read this : https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-long-sequences-long-short-term-memory-recurrent-neural-networks/

Answer (score -1):

The real potential of LSTM models for time series forecasting can be exploiting by building a global model using all the time series, instead as a univariate model, which actually ignores any cross series information available across your time series.

We implement the use case you are referring to by introducing a '**Moving Window Approach**' strategy that involves modeling a multiple input and output mapping, where you can pool time series that have different lengths. More detailed discussion of this strategy is described in **section 3.4** on our paper[1]. Here, you basically produce multiple input and output tuples for the given set of time series you have and then pool them to together for the LSTM training purposes. This accommodates even if you have time series with different lengths.

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03222.pdf

Comment: Pleas include relevant parts of the document in the answer, so that it the link ever breaks, the answer remains meaningful.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Thanks for your thoughtful feedback. I updated the answer to reflect only the relevant parts of the paper.